# Magento table rate shipping - exclude some regions from shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have setup a table rate shipping in Magento 1.9. I need to exclude some region from shipping.

For eg., In CSV there are 2 rows, in this format:

```
Country code - Region - postal - thrashhold - shipping cost
1. FR     - Corsica -   * -         0   -            18
2. *      -  *      -   * -         0   -            50
```

Currently, If I select France - Corsica in shipping calculator, then it returns shipping cost as 18, which is correct. If I select France - any other region then it shows shipping cost 50, which is not as requirement. Is it possible to restrict other regions, if I select France - any other region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got it. I need to remove the regions from tables: directory_country_region and directory_country_region_name, then it wont give option to select other regions of France. Then the shipping can be restricted for these regions.

Answer (score 0):

As per your CSV format condition on 2nd line is applied for all the location except FR-Corsica.You need to remove the second line then It must work as expected.

Comment: That I know, But I need to apply shipping rule for other countries as well and that will be 50$.

Comment: Then instead of using *-* add those countries where you want to provide the shipping as using* is applied to everything except the condition present in CSV.

Comment: Just remove the second line and add countries you wish to provide shipping with * in region field for all the countries

Comment: I want to have all countries, I need to limit regions.

Comment: This is the standard way of magento to handle shipping rates If you are uising any external module then you can check in admin setting also.But best way is to add shipping rule in CSV where shipping is available for rest of all it will show no quotes available

Answer (score 0):

Only change order of rows

Example:

```
   Country code - Region - postal - thrashhold - shipping cost
1. *       -      *          -         * -         0 -     50
2. FR      -      Corsica    -         * -         0 -     18
```